# Exporting typescript interfaces gives eslint error

Tags: typescript, eslint

Package.json:

```
"eslint": "^4.16.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
"eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^1.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^2.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
"eslint-plugin-typescript": "^0.10.0",
"typescript": "^2.7.2",
"typescript-eslint-parser": "^14.0.0"
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "browser": false,
  },
  "parser": "typescript-eslint-parser",
  "plugins": ["typescript"],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": true,
      "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": true
    }
  }
};
```

Still can't export typescript interfaces without warnings in WebStorm 2017.3:

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: @BenjaminLucidarme Eslint is more mature

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to add this to your eslint config ?

```
overrides: {
  files: ['**/*.ts'],
  parser: 'typescript-eslint-parser',
  rules: {
   'no-undef': 'off'
}
```

Comment: Tried it. No effect :/

Comment: I am sorry that didn't resolve your issue. This is still a known [issue](https://github.com/eslint/typescript-eslint-parser#known-issues) and seems to me this is the only workaround [here](https://github.com/eslint/typescript-eslint-parser/issues/416#issuecomment-363115171)

Comment: So great to hear that! Would you like to mark this answer as correct to help others?

Comment: this method only off the eslint rule  "no-undef", i don't think it's a good solution

Comment: It just ignoring any no-undef rule at your project and make eslint less effective